# Trying to add a Favorites model to my app...getting routing errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app where there is a predefined list of Drinks that the users can view. I am trying to give users the ability to favorite/unfavorite a drink.

For some reason I am getting an AssociationMismatch error when I click on the favorite link. Apparently the code is not liking my current_user.favorite_drinks << @drink part of the code

*CONTROLLER* drinks_controller.rb

```
def favorite
  type = params[:type]
  if type == "favorite"
    @drink = Drink.find params[:drink_id]
    current_user.drinks << @drink
      redirect_to :back, notice: 'You favorites #{@drink.name}'
    elsif type == "unfavorite"
      current_user.drinks.delete(@drink)
      redirect_to :back, notice: 'You unfavorited #{@drink.name}'
    else
    redirect_to :back, notice: 'Nothing happened'
  end
end
```

CONTROLLER favorites_controller.rb

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user
    @drinks = @user.favorite_drinks.all
    render action: :show
  else
    render file: 'public/404', status: 404, formats: [:html]
  end
end
```

ROUTES routes.rb

match 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
  match 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
  match 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'signout'

root to: "drinks#index"
  resources :glasses
  resources :ingredients
  resource  :cabinet
  resources :drinks do
    get 'favorite', :on => :collection
  end
  resources :favorites

get "favorites/show"

MODEL user.rb

```
     has_one :cabinet
     has_many :favorite_drinks
     has_many :drinks, through: :favorite_drinks
```

MODEL favorite_drink.rb

```
    attr_accessible :drink_id, :user_id

    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :drink
```

VIEW _results.html.haml

```
   %td= link_to "favorite", favorite_drinks_path(drink_id: drink.id, type: "favorite"), method: "get"
   %td= link_to "unfavorite", favorite_drinks_path(drink, type: "unfavorite"), method: "get"
```

VIEW favorites/show.html.haml

```
   %table.table.table-striped
     %thead
       %tr
         %th Name
     %tbody
       - if @drinks.each do |drink|
         %tr
           %td= link_to drink.name, drink
```

*My Updated Code*

Migration create_favorite_drinks.rb

```
    class CreateFavoriteDrinks < ActiveRecord::Migration
     def change
       create_table :favorite_drinks do |t|
         t.integer :drink_id
         t.integer :user_id

         t.timestamps
       end
     end
   end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 things on that part of the code causing errors

1. @drink is an array so you need to iterate through each one before you add them to the list of favorite drinks of a user using `<<`
2. current_user.favorite_drinks << @drink - you are pushing a `Drink` object to a `favorite_drinks` table which is why you have a mismatch

The best solution to this is to setup your model like this

```
# user.rb
has_many :favorite_drinks
has_many :drinks, through: :favorite_drinks

# favorite_drink.rb
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :drink

# drink.rb
has_many :favorite_drinks
has_many :users, through: :favorite_drinks
```

This is assuming that you have a `user_id` and `drink_id` on the `favorites_drinks` table.  Then you can just use `current_user.drink_ids = params[:drink_ids]`

UPDATE:

I just noticed that you are using `params[:drink_id]`. so change the controller code to

```
@drink = Drink.find params[:drink_id]
current_user.drinks << @drink
```

And you should be fine

UPDATE: move @drink out of the if block so you still access to it when the type is unfavorite

```
@drink = Drink.find params[:drink_id]

if type == "favorite"
  current_user.drinks << @drink
  redirect_to :back, notice: 'You favorites #{@drink.name}'
elsif type == "unfavorite"
  current_user.drinks.delete(@drink)
  redirect_to :back, notice: 'You unfavorited #{@drink.name}'
else
  redirect_to :back, notice: 'Nothing happened'
end
```

Comment: I am now getting a "unknown attribute: user_id" with in the favorite controller.

Comment: that doesn't help at all.  what did you change?  please update your question if you changed anything at all.

Comment: Updated with what i changed. not quite sure where the user_id is coming from

Comment: My problem was stemming from my migration. I did not have a drink_id or user_id column and once i added that I was able to successfully favorite drinks. I am now faced with the problem of not being able to unfavorite the drink. I am getting an "AssociationTypeMismatch NilClass" error when I click unfavorite. My code has been revised to show my changes